# How to fix 'Error processing method: 'System.Void Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService' error in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism, azure-pipelines

After updating Prism NuGet package 7.2.0.1367 to my Xamarin.Forms project, Azure pipelines fails to build. The local build succeeds as does App Center build.

**I'm getting the following error in Azure Pipelines**:

> "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2053,5):
>   error MSB4018: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method:
>   'System.Void
>   Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService::ConfigureTabbedPage(Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage,System.String)'
>   in assembly: 'Prism.Forms.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException:
>   Failed to resolve System.String[]
>   System.String::Split(System.Char,System.StringSplitOptions)
>   [/Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/MasterDetailTabbed/MasterDetailTabbed.Android/MasterDetailTabbed.Android.csproj]"

**PackageReference**:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Prism.Unity.Forms" Version="7.2.0.1367" />
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.1.0.673156" />
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.2.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You can find a [sample project](https://github.com/Sw1ma/prism-samples/tree/master/MasterDetailTabbed) regarding this issue on GitHub. It will demonstrate MasterDetailPage navigation in combination with **TabbedPages**.

I'm kind of lost here, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show your android csproj file ?

Comment: @Roubachof, you can find it [here](https://github.com/Sw1ma/prism-samples/blob/master/MasterDetailTabbed/MasterDetailTabbed.Android/MasterDetailTabbed.Android.csproj) as part of the sample project. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: try disable AndroidUseAapt2

Comment: Also, it already happened to me when I forgot to update the Xamarin sdk version (example Xamarin.Android 9.3 is the latest). If prism was built with the latest version and sdk is not up to date in azure it could result in this kind of error.

Comment: Unfortunately, playing arround with AndroidUseAapt2 or AndroidLinkMode didn't do the trick. Probably Azure isn't up-to-date? How could I easily determine which SDK version Prism uses or get an update on Azure :)?

Comment: You cannot know which against which SDK prism has been compiled. And unfortunately I never used Azure Pipelines. But there must be a way to specify Xamarin Android SDK version in it: this is your quest

Comment: @Roubachof, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the buid configuration to **Debug** solved the build problem.

```
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

...

steps:
- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*droid*.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Probably the **Debug** build configuration is setting the *AndroidLinkMode* to **None**.  I didn't properly investigated it but it is most likely, see [Linking on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker) for more information.

A next step could be [Preserving Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/linker#preserving-code).